# autoware.auto lgsvl Message type sensor_msgs/PointCloud2 does not have a field header.seq

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to reproduce the AVP demo on branch master: https://autowarefoundation.gitlab.io/autoware.auto/AutowareAuto/avpdemo.html

As indicated in the documentation, I have:

- started lgsvl launched
- autoware_auto_visualization.launch.py
- launched ms3_sim.launch.py

From there, I start the lgsvl simulation and the autoware_auto_visualization.launch.py terminal is spammed by errors like:

> ```
> [rosbridge_websocket-3] [ERROR] [1617948492.535521192] [gui.rosbridge_server_node]: [Client 0] publish: Message type sensor_msgs/PointCloud2 does not have a field header.seq
> ```

When the problem occurs, the simulation seems to run fine, and LGSVL says it is properly connected to rosbrige
On Rviz side I cannot get to visualize any message from the simulation

Example logs: https://gitlab.com/-/snippets/2102935

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/375767/autoware.auto-lgsvl-message-type-sensor_msgs/pointcloud2-does-not-have-a-field-header.seq/) by [vrichard](https://answers.ros.org/users/36745/vrichard/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2021-04-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You might be using the ROS bridge instead of the ROS2NativeBridge in your vehicle config as `seq` is a field that doesn't exist in ROS2 header messages anymore.

---

Originally posted by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) with karma: 1766 on 2021-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vrichard](https://answers.ros.org/users/36745/vrichard/) on 2021-04-12**:
Indeed, I overlooked the documentation.